# Show User Account Age

Tags: php, datetime

I want to display my users registered ages (how long they have been registered).
I use this line of code to show the registered date in my user controller:

```
$D->date_register = pstrftime($this->lang('usr_info_birthdate_dtformat'), $u->reg_date);
```

And this in the HTML:

```
<?= $D->date_register ?>
```

The registered date (reg_date) is an int(10) in the database (unix timestamp).  I know I have to subtract reg_date from the current time to get the account age, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The method outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3923228/817496) is probably best.  Just create two DateTime objects, one for reg_date and one for the current time, diff them, and use the resulting object.

Comment: i use that and i have this error ! Fatal error: Call to a member function diff() on a non-object in

Comment: Try using the [setTimstamp method](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php) instead of providing the timestamp when you create the object.  As far as I can tell, DateTime doesn't like unix timestamps in the constructor.

Comment: `$my_time_object = new DateTime(); $my_time_object->setTimestamp($unix_timestamp_from_database);`